# How to change geometry attributes dynamically using dat GUI in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a sphere geometry with this function

```
let createBall = () => {
  let geoBall = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 32, 16);
  let mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "red", transparent: true });

  ball = new THREE.Mesh(geoBall, mat);
  ball.position.set(0, 5, 0);
  ball.geometry.dynamic = true;
  ball.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  ball.geometry.__dirtyVertices = true;

  scene.add(ball);
};
```

and I call the function in window.onload function. I also use dat GUI to edit the geometry attribute which was the widthSegment of the ball.geometry like this

```
 ballFolder
    .add(ball.geometry.parameters, "widthSegments", 1, 64, 1)
    .onChange(function () {
      console.log(geoBall);
      ball.geometry.dispose();
      ball.geometry = geoBall.clone();
    });
```

when I log the geoBall in the console, it turns out that the attribute has changed, but the object itself isn't changed. Anyone know how to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

The values in `parameters` are only used when the geometry is created. Think of the geometry generators (`BoxGeometry`, `SphereGeometry` etc.) as factory methods. Changing the parameters has no effect once the object is created.

So I suggest you create a new geometry in your `onChange()` callback and call `dispose()` on the previous one (what you already do).

BTW: In recent `three.js` version geometry objects do not have `dynamic`, `verticesNeedUpdate` and `__dirtyVertices` properties.

Comment: by creating new geometry do you mean creating the SphereGeometry or the Mesh? I've tried creating new Mesh with the changed SphereGeometry attributes in onChange() callback function. But it turns out that the new created object is still the same as the previous one. I use console.log() to see the new object attributes and the attributes is different with what the scene should be showing

Comment: Just replace the geometry. Not the entire mesh. This is how the geometry browser in the documentation is implemented: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/SphereGeometry

Comment: I did that, and still, the loaded object is not what it should be.. I even tried making a new mesh in the `onChange()` using the new geometry. But the result is still the same!

Comment: Please show what you do with a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/